# Transit through Singapore on a new Russian passport

Tags: airport-transfer, singapore, russian-citizens

I'm a Russian citizen living in New Zealand. I will be flying to Russia, transferring in Singapore. As far as I've found out, I need a visa to enter Singapore? Is it a tourist one? And I'm waiting for my new passport, which may arrive just before I will be leaving. So if I get transit visa in my old passport, can I bring both new and old passports and transfer through, or does it have to be in my new passport?

Comment: Are you going to leave the airport in Singapore? Or just change planes?

Comment: Just change planes. Have another flight in 5 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Singapore allows visa-free airport transit. Moreover, if you want to have a layover in the city, Singapore offers 96-hour [visa free transit facility (VFTF)](http://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=96) for Russian passport holders. Also see [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=RU&AR=NZ&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=RU&EM=NZ&TR=SG&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C).

As to visas, Singapore issues them electronically, they are not stamped in your passport. You may apply for a visa as soon as you know your new passport number.

Comment: Your Timatic link doesn't seem to work anymore: "USER DOES NOT HAVE TIMATIC WEB ACCESS"

Comment: @alkar Don't think I am able or willing to do anything about that.